# How to use Kotlin suspend StateIn function inside a viewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow

I have this block of code in my ViewModel:

```
val employeeState: StateFlow<EmployeeDataState> =
        employeeRepository.fetch()
            .map(EmployeeDataUiState::Success)
            .stateIn(
                scope = viewModelScope,
                started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
                initialValue = EmployeeDataState.Loading,
            )
```

EDIT:

```
suspend fun fetchEmployees() = flow {
        try {
            val result = employeesApiService.fetchEmployees()
            emit(result)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            //emit(emptyList())
        }
    }
```

`employeeRepository.fetch()` is a suspend function which connects to the retrofit API.

The problem is I get an error that `fetch` has to be inside a coroutine scope. I can change my code to use `viewModelScope.launch { ..}` but in that case I am not sure how would I use `stateIn` function. Any help on how can use `stateIn()` to call a suspend method. I also saw there's an overloaded `suspend` method for it but now sure how would I use it.

Comment: The problem is that your fetch() function is suspending. It’s a code smell for a suspend function to return a Flow. Can you share your implementation of that function?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Added the repository code

Comment: Just remove `suspend` from the function signature. You don't need to suspend to create a Flow since they are just a description of a behavior, not synchronously running the behavior before the Flow is returned. Also, do not catch all Exception types in a Flow or a coroutine, because this breaks cancellation functionality. It's a code smell universally to catch Exceptions of any type, but if you're going to do it, you at least need to rethrow the exception if it's a CancellationException.

Comment: I see, makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Tenfour04 : In dong so, how would I make sure repository methods are thread-safe as I would need to make them suspend to use corotuineContenxt?

Comment: It depends entirely on your repository implementation how you would do that, if you even need to. For instance, if you're passing through suspend functions from Room, Firebase, Retrofit, etc., they are already thread-safe.